# How come divs aren't lining up with flex in ternary

Tags: reactjs

I am making a page, I have a cancel and a submit button.

The cancel button should be inline to the right hand side of the submit button. I have tried labelling the same class with flex. and added the property flex row with a width of 100% and it is not displaying next too eachother.

Not to sure why this is the case. The buttons are correctly used with flex-end I just don't want them stacking on top of each other and expected output is the submit button then the cancel button inline with eachother.

[image: Butttons displayed]

Buttons.js

```
 {!users ? null :
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="userStyles" >
        <Button 
          text={!showAddUsersToRole ? 'Add Users to Role' : 'Cancel'}
          onClick={onAddUsersToRoleClick}
          className='Button Dark Main'
        />
  </div>

  {!showAddUsersToRole ? null :
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className='userStyles' >

      <Button
        text='Submit'
        onClick={onSubmitClick}
        className='Button Dark Main'
      />

     
      </div>
   
 
    </React.Fragment>
  }
 }
```

CSS:

```
.userStyles {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: '10px';
  margin-top: '10px';
  padding: 10px;  
}
```

Comment: Do you have two `. userStyles` divs with one button in each? Don't you want them both to be in a single `.userStyles` div?

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the two buttons with an element that has the class name `.userStyles` :

```
<div className="userStyles" >
 {!users ? null :
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <Button 
          text={!showAddUsersToRole ? 'Add Users to Role' : 'Cancel'}
          onClick={onAddUsersToRoleClick}
          className='Button Dark Main'
        />
  </div>

  {!showAddUsersToRole ? null :
    <React.Fragment>
      <div  >

      <Button
        text='Submit'
        onClick={onSubmitClick}
        className='Button Dark Main'
      />

     
      </div>
   
 
    </React.Fragment>
  }
}
 </div>
```